# Print only index of a string array that are not null in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I've following array of strings. Default value of each string is set to `string.Empty`. And this array is returned by a fuction. Now, I want to print only those indexes that are not null. I can use if-else for each index but it could be very long way for going through 8 items. is there any short way so that I can print only those items that are not nulll

```
string [] muniSearches = {airSearchReport, certOfOccupancy, emerRepair, fire, fZone,foSearch, health, hsVoilation};
```

Comment: I tried by conventional if-else

Comment: a for loop for 8 items is not long ! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Select` and return the provided index if the value is `null`:

```
var indexesNotNull = muniSearches.Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i })
                                 .Where(x => x.Value != null)
                                 .Select(x => x.Index);
```

Or simply using a `for` loop:

```
List<int> indexesNotNull = new List<int>();
for (int index = 0; index < muniSearches.Length; index++)
{
    if (muniSearches[index] != null)
    {
        indexesNotNull.Add(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use !string.IsNullEmpty(muniSearches[index]) as the OP said something like the strings might be initialized as string.empty.

Comment: If an empty string is the default, and OP wants to know the null's, this is the answer that fits the question. If the question is different, you might be right.

Comment: Tbh, i think OP is mixing up null and string.Empty ;)

Comment: That is certainly possible. That is why you should keep your comment @lokusking

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't clear whether you wanted values or indexes.
If you want values and you can use linq in the context, that's fairly straight forward.

```
muniSearches
.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
.ToList()
.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

If you want indexes, that's again doable but a little more involed.  Something like:

```
muniSearches
.Select((s, i) => new {value = s, index = i})
.Where(o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.value))
.Select(o => o.index)
.ToList()
.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Where do you provide the index, as OP asked?

Comment: Wasn't clear about that, updated with a second option.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of that string using lambda expressions syntax and then store the index of the string having any data in that.

```
var Indexes = muniSearches.Select((Value, Index) => new { Value , Index })
                             .Where(x => x.Value.Length > 0)
                             .Select(x => x.Index);
```